# Update/insert data programmatically in bigquery

Tags: insert, google-bigquery

I would like to insert/update records within Bigquery tables programmatically (either through API/SQL). Does Bigquery support this?

Comment: can you elaborate on what you are looking for?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible to update individual BigQuery records, but it is possible to append data to an existing table. You can insert a data load job via the API, or you can use the ["bq" command line client](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/cli_tool) or the [BigQuery Web UI](https://developers.google.com/bigquery/docs/browser_tool)

For more info about loading data into BigQuery, see: https://developers.google.com/bigquery/loading-data-into-bigquery

Answer (score 0):

Update, BigQuery now supports INSERT